# const vs. macro and memory lifespan

Tags: c++, c

I have a huge array that is written literally thanks to a script. It is basically an image file converted to an array.

I could define the body as a macro or put it into a const type in a header. If I did set it as a const, what will be the memory lifespan? Does it last for the entire program? Does it last for as long as the scope it's used in, like in a function? Would using macros be a better option?

Comment: whats wrong with including the actual bitmap itself?

Comment: Well, you can't include a bitmap in C/C++ code - except if you convert the bitmape to code(which is what he's doing) - or add the bitmap as a resource file if you're on win32

Comment: resource file, open it from disk, etc...

Comment: @reuscam I use to do it that way, but I'm porting the code where the file system is closed off. It also makes it highly portable. No worries about if certain image libraries exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd move the array definition into a source file (probably by itself):

```
// bitmap.cpp
char const my_bitmap[] = {
   0x12, 0x34, 0x56, // lots of data here...
};
```

Then write a header that *just* has an extern declaration for it:

```
//bitmap.h
extern char const my_bitmap[];
```

This gives all code (that includes the header) access to the data, but assures that you only have one copy of the data for everybody to use. It also avoids pointlessly re-compiling the code that represents the bitmap, once for each file that needs access to the data.

Comment: What about the memory implications? Really, I only ever have to use it once.

Comment: Managing that memory will (mostly) be up to the OS. Assuming demand-paged virtual memory, it'll get paged in when used, and discarded when it hasn't been used recently (exact details of determining "recently" vary).

Answer (score 2):

If the array is defined in a header file, that array will have global scope, and it will live as long as the application lasts.

Note, if you include that header multiple times,you'll likely get a linker error stating you have the same symbol/name several places. If the array is static, you'll have a copy of that array in every source file that includes that header.

If you defined the array as a macro, it'll live according to where you use that macro, and you will get a copy of the array every place you use that macro - doesn't sound like a good solution in all but the simple cases where the array is quite small.